# ImportError: cannot import name 'adam_v2' from 'keras.optimizers' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/optimizers/__init__.py)

Tags: python, keras, optimization, google-colaboratory, adam

ImportError: cannot import name 'adam_v2' from 'keras.optimizers' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/optimizers/**init**.py)

I tried downloading the updated Keras version but still it didn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.